# Commit -m not working after staging changes

Tags: linux, git, github, git-commit, git-config

I've used git many times before but since I made a new Linux installation, I've not been able to commit my changes. I keep receiving this error:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <my@mail.com>) not allowed
```

So of course, I run the steps provided with my own credentials and I keep receiving the same error every time I try to commit changes.

```
    git config -l --show-origin
    file:/home/george/.gitconfig    user.email=my@mail.com
    file:/home/george/.gitconfig    user.name=George Lastname
    file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
    file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
    file:.git/config        core.bare=false
    file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
    file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://github.com/mygithub/repo
    file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    file:.git/config        branch.master.remote=origin
    file:.git/config        branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Is there some chance that you've installed two different versions of Git, one of which uses `/home/george/.gitconfig` for `--global` settings and one of which uses some other directory for `--global` settings?

Answer (score 1):

Git needs to know your personal name (`user.name`) and email address (`user.email`) in order to embed these values in your commits and tags.  In your case, you have a valid email address, but you haven't specified a personal name.

You should run the `git config` command that sets `user.name` as suggested above.  Note that this is not your username on any system, but your personal name (e.g., "Pat Doe" or "Sam Smith").  Credentials are unrelated to this in any way.

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, I still keep getting the same error. Is there a way I can reset the global username and email?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `git config -l ---show-origin` as a code block.

Comment: It shows my global user and email correctly and updates when I run the git config commands.